# SSRS : Repeating table with multiple-value parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I'm struggling with something which is probably easy in reporting services, but could not find any online help on this.

I'm building a telephony report for my company that show statistics for our clients. The main parameters for this report are : client name, date from, date to

Each client can have several calls queues (not the same number for each) so I need to create a statistics table that shows numbers, and repeats itself for each call queue.

I created a multi-values parameter for the queues that populates itself from this query:

```
SELECT queue_id FROM customers WHERE customer_name = @Customer
```

The subreports parameters are:

```
date_from = [@date_from]
date_to = [@date_to]
queueid = =Split(join(Parameters!client_call_queues.Value,","),",")
```

And here comes the issue, when I show the report preview, I can see the table with values, but summed for all queues, not splitted.

If I add a custom grouping on the tablix, it returns me a wrong calculation.

To go deeper in details, here's below a first printscreen that shows the numbers for all the queues:

[image]

and the table I get from the subreport, without custom grouping:

[image]

I tried to add this custom grouping, in the subreport tablix:

[image]

And here's the result it gives with that grouping:

[image]

Here's below the query used to populate subreport tablix:

```
SELECT
@queueid,
ISNULL(q1.[Day],'TOTAL') AS [Day],
COUNT(*) AS [Calls In],
SUM(CASE WHEN q1.[Call Type] = 'Answered Within Threshold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) + SUM(CASE WHEN q1.[Call Type] = 'Answered After Threshold' THEN 1 ELSE 
0 END) AS [Answered],
SUM(CASE WHEN q1.[Call Type] = 'Abandoned Within Threshold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) AS [Abd. Within Threshold],
SUM(CASE WHEN q1.[Call Type] IN ('Abandoned Within Threshold') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(*)) AS [Calls Abandoned Within Threshold 
Rate],
SUM(CASE WHEN q1.[Call Type] = 'Abandoned After Threshold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) AS [Abd. After Threshold],
SUM(CASE WHEN q1.[Call Type] IN ('Abandoned After Threshold') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(*)) AS [Calls Abandoned After Threshold 
Rate],
SUM(CASE WHEN q1.[Call Type] = 'Voicemail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Voice 
Mail]
FROM
(   
    SELECT
    CUS.[Customer],
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,ACD.[startdatetime],121),1,10) AS [Day],
    ACD.[sessionid],  
    ACD.[contactdisposition],
    ISNULL(ACD.[Squeuetime],0) AS [Squeuetime],
    CUS.[ans_speed_secs],
    CUS.[abd_tresh],
    ACD.[businesshours],
    ACD.[contacttype],
    ISNULL(ACD.[connecttime],0) AS [connecttime],
    ACD.[voicemail],
    CUS.[ans_speed_rate],
    ACD.[callednumber],
    CUS.[Active],
    ISNULL(ACD.[Stalktime], 0) AS [Stalktime],
    ISNULL(ACD.[Sholdtime], 0) AS [Sholdtime],
    CASE
    WHEN ACD.[contactdisposition] = 2 AND ISNULL(ACD.[Squeuetime],0) <= CUS.
    [ans_speed_secs] THEN 'Answered Within Threshold'
    WHEN ACD.[contactdisposition] = 2 AND ISNULL(ACD.[Squeuetime],0) > CUS.
    [ans_speed_secs] THEN 'Answered After Threshold'
    WHEN ACD.[contactdisposition] <> 2 AND ISNULL(ACD.[Squeuetime],0) <= 
    CUS.[abd_tresh] THEN 'Abandoned Within Threshold'
    WHEN ACD.[contactdisposition] <> 2 AND ISNULL(ACD.[Squeuetime],0) > CUS.
    [abd_tresh] THEN 'Abandoned After Threshold'
    WHEN ACD.[voicemail] = 'VoiceMail' THEN 'Voicemail'
    END AS [Call Type]
    FROM [ACD].[dbo].[UccxCallsQuery2] ACD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [ACD].[dbo].[Customers] CUS ON ACD.[callednumber] = CUS.
    [Called_id]
    WHERE CUS.[ACDSelection] IN (@queueid)
    AND ACD.[businesshours] <> 'NBO' 
    AND ACD.[contacttype] = 1 
    AND CUS.[Active] = 1
    AND CONVERT(DATE,ACD.[startdatetime]) BETWEEN @date_from AND @date_to
) q1 GROUP BY q1.[Day] WITH ROLLUP
```

I guess this is only a simple thing, but can spot it.

Thanks in advance for any help on this !

Comment: Two way s to approach this. First is to have a single report, grouped by queue_id, this sounds like what you are trying to do. Second way is to have a subreport that handles only a single queue_id and a master report that has a dataset containing the list of queue_ids and a table. the table cell would contain your subreport with the individual queue_id passed to it as a parameter. As you said you got incorrect calc when grouping perhaps it's best to show what you are getting now and what you expect to see along with your report design and a sample of data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added some screen captures in the initial post. I would rather go to the second way you suggested: The goal in the end is to have the master report automatically generated into PDF, and for each client the statistics for each queue must be displayed in several tablix when applicable, with one repeated on new pages.